# Permissions on a site document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, modern-experience, site-collection

For permissions if I have a user that needs to access a document library on a site collection can I grant them access just to the document library and not the site collection as a whole.

If I do will there be any ramifications other than not being able to move around the site.

Comment: Hi @David, Did you try my suggestions given below? Is it working for you?

Comment: If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible in SharePoint online.

You have to break the permissions inheritance at document library level and then you can grant specific permissions on document library.

Check this documentation for detailed information and steps: [Customize permissions for a SharePoint list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782)

---

While breaking permissions inheritance at document library, it will keep the default site permissions/groups (up to this point) in document library unique permissions. You can keep those groups or remove as per your requirements.

But, after breaking permissions if you make any changes in site permissions like adding new groups/users directly in site permissions, those will not be propagated to the library permissions as document library now have unique permissions.